# Python findall - ignoring some results

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, findall

I'm doing a program that in the future will interpret the search results of videos from YouTube. My snippet version of code is aimed to extract pseudonyms of artists from the song title.

## Example

I have a title saved in string: **"Drake ft. DJ Khalid, Nicki Minaj - 'Why Futures' (Official video)"**  and I would like to ignore the word 'Futures' for *findall* function (because it is part of title song, it is not rapper's/artist's nick), which is between the ' and " characters.
Additionally I have a problem with 'DJ Khalid' because *findall* returns two nicks of rappers (DJ Khalid and Khalid) instead one nick (should be same DJ Khalid).

## Code

```
edit_string = "Drake ft. DJ Khalid, Nicki Minaj - &quot;Why Futures&quot; (Official video)"
rapper_name = open_csv() #list of rapper's nicks

new_title = []
for rapper_name in rappers_list:
  yer = ''.join(rapper_name)
  if re.findall(yer.lower(),edit_string.lower()): new_title.append(yer)
new_title = ' x '.join(new_title)
print(new_title)
edit_string = new_title
```

## Results

Actual result is: `Drake x Khalid x Nicki Minaj x DJ Khalid x Future` (because in my list of rappers unfortunately I have someone who is called Future)

Shall be: `Drake x DJ Khalid x Nicki Minaj`

How to do it in the best possible way (best optimisation)? Thank you in advance for all your help.

Comment: Might need to use `wordbounds \b` with the `r` option. How many artists are in your list? Secondly, how do you deal with things like "DJ Khalid"? Third, 'I been moving calm don't start no trouble with me'... (I had to)

Comment: I have around 300 rappers. After added "DJ Khalid" (forgot about him <pepeHands>) into my list unfortunately I have another problem:
with updated string: `edit_string  = "Drake ft. DJ Khalid, Nicki Minaj - &quot;Why Futures&quot; (Official video)"`
Actual result is:  `Drake x Khalid x Nicki Minaj x Future x DJ Khalid` :/

Comment: Replace `yer` with `yer = '(?i)\\b'+str(rapper_name)+'\\b'`.... and Replace `new_title.append(yer)` with `new_title.append(rapper_name)`

Comment: doesnt work (example of yer value = (?i)\b['Freddie Gibbs']\b), I was testing also b'string' as bytes/encode and result is the same

Comment: You're missing an extra `\ ` in font of the b's. Copy and paste what I have. It is `\\b`

Comment: Secondly `['Freddie Gibbs']` is an OR statement in regex. That's effectively `'` OR  `F` OR `r` O `e` OR `d`, etc. Really, copy and paste exactly what I did

Comment: I did but I just had another problem (`re.error: bad character range g-e at position 8`) but I fixed it - thanks a lot for help ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Credit to @FailSafe for pattern.  OP, this answer demonstrates what @FailSafe suggested is indeed correct:

```
import re

edit_string = "Drake ft. DJ Khalid, Nicki Minaj - &quot;Why Futures &quot; (Official video)"
rappers_list = ['Drake', 'DJ Khalid', 'Nicki Minaj', 'Future']#open_csv() #list of rapper's nicks

new_title = []
for rapper_name in rappers_list:
    yer = '(?i)\\b'+str(rapper_name)+'\\b'
    if re.findall(yer.lower(), edit_string.lower()): 
        new_title.append(rapper_name)
new_title = ' x '.join(new_title)
print(new_title)
edit_string = new_title  

Output: 
## Drake x DJ Khalid x Nicki Minaj
```

Comment: bless for help guys